# How to get a count of page views and display it on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, analytics

I have a Rails App that has articles and collections.

Rails App 3.2.14
Ruby 1.9.3

One a user is signed, he/she can create collections and put articles inside of it. The user can then email this article out a client. The client can click on a link and visit the collection ( essentially show the collection, but not edit it in anyway ).

How would I go about tracking how many total views and unique views a collection receives?

Comment: Add google analytics to your site. It's definitely the easiest and most robust solution. EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see that you also wanted to display it. n/m.

Answer (score 1):

I increment an integer entry on the database every time a user access the articles. This can be done through the controller method that is called to display your articles.

Comment: What exactly is an "integer entry"? Do you have any open source code you could share? Is there a way to track the views and uniqe views with this integer entry? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out gems like this one: [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist)

Comment: Does impressionist log particular URL views or just views on collections?

Comment: Log requests to particular "controller/action/id". I don't know how you have structured your app, but e.g. it will log that www.example.com/forum/posts/1 has 15 unique views.

Comment: Do you know if there's a good way to incorporate javascript into this?

Comment: You will have to be more specific on what you mean by - incorporating javascript. This particular gem detects and logs requests to the specified controller/action, which is pretty much - server-side.